# How to pass a textbox value to another jsp page via <a href tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

In the above JSP i am trying to pass the text box value through href tag. I came across the above syntax in stackoverflow. But it does not seem to be working. Need help.

**HTML**

```
<input id="orderedItems" type="text" name="orderedItems" value="hiii" /> 
<a href='products.jsp?id=1&loginid=${userName}&orderim='+ document.getElementById('orderedItems').value;>
```

Comment: <input id="orderedItems" type="text" name="orderedItems" value="hiii" />
        
<a href='products.jsp?id=1&loginid=${userName}&orderim='+ document.getElementById('orderedItems').value;>

Comment: @vaisshnaiv janani, can you confirm the answer or how you solved this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the href attribute in the onchange event of the input.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/1xtv7jxq/)

```
var link = document.getElementById("link"),
    txt = document.getElementById("txt"),
    baseUrl = link.href;

txt.onchange = function() {
    link.href = baseUrl + "?param=" + this.value;
};
```